# Running perf on ARM target

Tags: linux, profiling, perf

I am trying to use perf tool on an ARM target. Is it possible to do 'perf annotate' on a different machine as the target has limited capabilities.

thanks,
GL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy `perf.data` and `vmlinux`(with debuginfo) to other machine and use:

```
perf annotate -i perf.data.target --vmlinux vmlinux.target <symbol>
```

Use `--source` option to annotate with source.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am yet to try this. One more question, I am trying this for an embedded system where name resolution is not working as some of the depending libraries are not available (It is little difficult to get these compiled). Can I run the perf data run against the extracted rootfs on host itself?